# Restrict link with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I need to restrict access to any link that contains the word `user`.

My rewrite rule looks like this

```
RewriteRule (^|/)user(/|$) - [F,L]
```

It works fine when http://sitename.com/user is used but does not work for http://sitename.com/?q=user

Can anyone suggest a fix for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check the request uri and the query string separately like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  !^123\.456\.789\.123$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/user$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=user$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I forgot to mantion this is used to restrict access from only one IP address

Comment: @user2366317 I've updated the code to show one restricted IP address (123.456.789.123). If you want to restrict a whole subnet change that line to: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^123\.456\.789` and that will restrict all 123.456.789.* ip addresses

Comment: thanks so much , but what i was truing to do is allow access to user link from only this ip and block everyone else. can this be done ? thank you

Comment: Yes you can! code is now updated to ONLY allow users from the given IP address. Notice the `!` in front of the IP address. That means if the ip address is NOT 123.456.789.123 and user is in the uri or query string then redirect

Comment: this just blocked access completely to the site . hmm what am i doing wrong ?